# Email depending on the tab

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet in Google Sheets where the master tab has all information (manual input) then `=filter` is used to filter data accordingly throughout 12 tabs. Each tab corresponds to a different email address.

How can each email address receive an email when a row is added on their tab? I do have a script as a general email but not good to me on this occasion as it would email whoever I wanted when something has changed and I want only by tabs.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You don't say how the data on the "master" sheet is generated - would you please edit your question to clarify this. It has a direct impact on your choices for triggering an email.

Comment: "I do have a script as a general email but not good to me on this occasion." Would you please explain why it is "not good for you".

Comment: Hi Tedinoz. I hace amended my question. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the code you have?

Comment: Hi Kessy. Forgot to mention that the script I have is for notification when a form is submitted which is not the case here

Comment: Please treat this as a learning opportunity. Thank you for sharing your spreadsheet - it is the kind of valuable information that normally would be provided in your original question. As you noted to @Kessy, there is no field in the Master that contains the destination email address - this too is very important and, again, the sort of information that would be important to include in your original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a Trigger to listen when the row is inserted.

With the `onEdit()` function you can then get the range of the cells that where edited.

See: [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit)

Example of the `onEdit()` function:

```
function onEdit(e){
  // Set a comment on the edited cell to indicate when it was changed.
  var range = e.range;
  range.setNote('Last modified: ' + new Date());
}
```

With this range you can now get the sheet of that range with [`getSheet()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getsheet) and with that you can do [`getSheetName()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet.html#getsheetname) and you will have done it, you have the name of the modified sheet.

Example of `getSheetName()` function:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

Logger.log(sheet.getSheetName());
```

Finally, you just need to send the email to the address that `getSheetName()` returned.

Comment: hi kessy. thank you. However email address are not on each tab so it would have to be added manually on the script. Perhaps an example would pic it better https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1aICST4h1rBidml2Y0zrEfrDN5HylftPfAruP2IH0jp4/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @PedroGuerreiro The email addresses do not necessarily have to be literally written into the script but, since you only have three addresses, this would be the easiest solution. One option would be to use an `if` statement (if store == "INVERNESS"){var email = "inverness@example.com" }else if (store == "GLASGOW"){var email = "glasgow@example.com"} else {var email = "edinburgh@example.com"} Another option would be to use the Javascript `switch` [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) - Stackoverflow has many examples for Google Sheets.

Comment: @PedroGuerreiro This is an excellent answer. FWIW, I have recently provided a [worked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59674651/1330560) on a similar theme. It may or may not complement the useful guidance provided by Kessy.